# Spring (kotlin) controller receives non-nullable parameters of a data class as null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, nullpointerexception, kotlin-null-safety

I am facing an unexpected error which I am not sure how to handle.

I have a data class like this:

```
data class Payload (
  @SerializedName("id")
  var id: String
  @SerializedName("type")
  var type: String,
  @SerializedName("data")
  var data: String
)
```

And a simple Spring controller like this:

```
@PostMapping("/some-endpoint")
fun dataHandler(@RequestBody payload: Payload): String{
    when (payload.type){
        "someType" -> {
            val result = try {
                gson.fromJson(payload.data, payloadData::class.java)
            } catch (e: Exception){
                throw BadDataException("Bad Data")
            }
            payloadProcessor.process(result, payload.id) // NPE here
        }
        "otherType" -> {
            doSomethingElseHere()
        }
    }
}
```

When the execution reaches payloadProcessor.process, a null pointer exception occurs as `id` is apparently null. On the other hand the object is created and the two remaining values seem to be properly populated.
If I add an if statement checking for null values, the ide complains that the the payload properties are never null, marking the if statement as redundant, but in reality this is not the case.
I was under the impression that null-safe properties are... well... null safe. At the very least I would expect the null pointer exception to occur once the object is constructed.

My question is:

- How does Spring manage to create such an object
- Why is this not detected upon the object construction
- What would be the "Kotlin" way to handle this as I would not like to check for null parameters in a supposedly null safe object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with Gson, not Spring. Gson is designed for use with Java, which has no* distinction between nullable and non-nullable types, so Gson will happily assign a null value anyways.

Unfortunately, there isn't a magic solution here. You can write your own [TypeAdapter](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) which explicitly checks for null values before constructing your data classes, but if you have a lot of classes, that's going to get very repetitive. Alternatively, you could create your own [TypeAdapterFactory](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/index.html?com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) and use Kotlin's reflection library to check which types are nullable and which are not, but that will have various implications with regards to performance and dependencies.

** There are nullability annotations (@Nonnull, @Nullable), but Gson doesn't check them.*

Comment: Thank you for your input. I thought about this, but in my case the nullPointerException is not on the object produced by gson.fromJson(), but on a property of the received object itself. In fact gson does the job as payload.data is not null. However payload.id is.

Comment: Yes, what's happening is when Gson deserializes your data, it assigns `null` to the `result.id` field, since in Java a `String` is nullable. There's no error until you try to use the value of `result.id`, since it's `null`.

Comment: Just to be clear, I am talking about `@RequestBody payload: Payload` and not `result = gson.fromJson(payload.data, payloadData::class.java)`where gson is making the conversion of the data property whish is assigned to result. I am not a gson expert, but how does gson affect the payload? The object is already constructed and is only used by gson to create a payloadData object. I am not performing any modifications on the payload itself, just reading its properties.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm assuming `payload` is being deserialized from a network request, could it be using Gson internally to deserialize and using `null` values there?

Comment: Does spring use gson internally? or does it use a similar mechanism of deserialisation? This is something my colleagues suggested as well and what I was suspecting but I would really like a concrete reason in order for me to avoid similar pitfalls in the future. I have writtem my own typeAdapter and so far it seems to perform ok. So if you could please update your response so that I can accept the answer.

Comment: @jsk If your custom `TypeAdapter` is working, then I would assume that Spring is using Gson internally. What would you like me to change about my answer?

Comment: Appologies. I should have been more clear yet again. I now receive the entire json as a String and instead of relying on spring, I create an object from it using the typeAdapter and gson. My initial question however was about the controller itself, in which case the problem was with how spring itself deals with the reqest. In your answer you focus on Gson as the core of the problem, which is not the case for my question. Your solution on the other hand was what I needed. I would simply suggest that you add spring as a potential breaking point (even as a sidenote) for the purposes of clarity.